# Boolean Resets When App Loads Wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

Hi I am still fairly new to C# & windows phone.

When the app Loads I wanted popup asking the user if they would like to do something

```
MessageBoxResult m = MessageBox.Show("Info.", "Question?", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
if (m == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
{                }                       
else if (m == MessageBoxResult.OK)
{  //Do Something }
```

Now that works fine, if the user says no I wanted a popup that asked the user if they would like reminding next time so U used

```
MessageBoxResult m = MessageBox.Show("Info.", "Question?", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
if (m == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
{     
    MessageBoxResult r = MessageBox.Show("", "Would You Like Reminding Next Time ?",MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
    if (r == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
    {   }
    else if (r == MessageBoxResult.OK)
    {   }
}                       
else if (m == MessageBoxResult.OK)
{  //Do Something  }
```

I need some kind of a switch, so when the app starts for the first time
app checks switch which is on,
they get asked a question

if they answer cancel,
they get asked if they want reminding

if they answer no,
set switch to off

I've tried to use a boolean but it just resets to true when the app closes, if i use a string it says a string cant be used as a bool

Any Advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings** to quickly save small values for example

```C#
// this will save my "your_key" to false;
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("your_key", false);
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save(); // make sure you call save

// so the next time the app runs I can get it back doing this
bool your_key = (bool) IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["your_key"];
```

But, should always enclose it in a try catch because the key might not exist

```C#
bool your_key = false;  // or default value
try
{
    your_key = (bool) IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["your_key"];
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

---

More Information can be found here:

[How to: Store and Retrieve Application Settings Using Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221360%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("first"))
{
   // Do your stuff
   IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["first"] = true;
   IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
}
```

This is all the code you need. 
Place everything you want to do only on first launch into this if statement. Then execute this code either in main page `Loaded` event or `OnNavigatedTo`.