# How to retain last setting value in windows phone application

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I  have a windows phone application in which two listpicker and one listbox in a form.
When i press a window start button or close the application and again start the application it does not retain the previous filter value can anybody give a solution .

Thanks

Comment: Save your settings to IsolatedStorage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798756/boolean-resets-when-app-loads-wp8/25799645#25799645  then restore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your App.xaml.cs file are two methods: Application_Activate and Application_Deactivate. In the deactivate function you have to store the current filter in the isolated storage, in your activate you have to load them. 
In your page.xaml.cs you have to use the loaded informations in the OnNavigatedTo function.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `Application Settings` of `Isolated Storage` where you could store and retrieve the values.

Check out this sample:

[Store and Retrieve Application Settings Using Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221360(v=vs.95).aspx)

Or else you could preserve the state of the page:

[How to preserve and restore page state for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff967548(v=vs.105).aspx)